# HP Proliant DL320 G5 CPU Fault Led

Tags: central-processing-unit, hp-proliant

My HP DL320 G5 will go through post, even start the boot sequence from the CD, but halts with the CPU Fault LED glowing red.

Each time I go back to BIOS the date is always reset to 2007. The server halts almost every time exiting BIOS (and writing changes).

I am able to run the memtest86+ with no signs of bad RAM.

What could be wrong with my server?

Comment: My thoughts are that your system is broken and you should call someone to get it repaired.

Comment: The phone number for HP Support in the USA is `800-334-5144`

Comment: At this point, call support.

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like your BIOS or Motherboard is fried. The BIOS isn't removable, but you can get replacement motherboards from HP (at a steep price) and find them online (eg eBay).

Answer (score 0):

Well, generally, as far as LED lights go, green or blue is good, and means everything is OK, yellow is bad, and means there's something wrong that might require attention, and red is very bad, and means that something is very wrong and definitely requires attention.

In this case, the red color of the CPU falut LED probably measns there's something wrong with the CPU.  Have you considered replacing it, or trying a different CPU you know works in this system?

Once you've done that, you can see if the BIOS clock keeps resetting to the manufacture or BIOS build date, and if it does, replacing the CMOS battery will probably fix that too.

Comment: If the CPU will run memtest, it's *probably* not bad, or at least mostly not bad. The crashing on BIOS/firmware interaction points to the MB being bad. No guarantees either way.

Answer (score 0):

Just to follow up, it turns out the the failing part was the power supply.
I found one on ebay for 40$ and the server is working fine now!